# En C como buscar en un directorio todos los nombres de archivos y guardarlos en un arreglo de strings de caracteres?

Tags: c

Cree un código para buscar todos los nombres de los archivos en un directorio, este código es recursivo por si encuentro otros directorios dentro del que estoy los revise. El recorrido dentro del directorio y búsqueda de archivos me funciona bien, ya que los he probado imprimiendo en pantalla lo que leo y me encuentra todo y no repite ningún nombre de archivo. El problema que tengo es que guarda dentro de un arreglo de strings de caracteres los nombres que vaya encontrando, así cuando encuentre todos los archivos tendré en el main el arreglo de strings lleno con todos los nombres de los archivos.El problema es que al final cuando imprime en pantalla ese arreglo, no están todos los archivos si no unos cuantos archivos repetidos. La meta final de este programa no es imprimir todos los nombres de archivos por pantalla, si no que me guarde en el arreglo todos los nombres de los archivos.Si me pueden ayudare que ya llevo dias sin encontrar la razon.

```
    void findfiles(char *root,char *p[],int *tam){
        DIR * dir;
        struct dirent *entrada;
        struct stat stt;
        dir = opendir(root);
        char *aux;
        char nombre[BUFFER_TAM];
        char buf[30];
        if (dir == NULL) {
                printf("hola4\n");
                return;
         }
     while ((entrada = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(entrada->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(entrada->d_name,"..")==0);
                else {
                    if (entrada->d_type == DT_DIR){
                        strcpy(nombre,root);
                        strcat(nombre,"/");
                        strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);
                        findfiles(nombre,p,tam);
                    }
                    else {
                        strcpy(nombre,root);
                        strcat(nombre,"/");
                        strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);
                        p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
                        p[*tam]=nombre;
                        *tam = *tam +1;
                    }
                }

            }


}


    void main(){
    char *archivos[BUFFER_TAM];
    char root[BUFFER_TAM]="/home/jesusmolina/Documentos";
    int i=0,tam=0;
    findfiles(root,archivos,&tam);
    for (i;i<tam;i++)
       printf("%s\n",archivos[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías simplificar tu código y evitar, en la medida de lo posible, duplicidades.

Esto:

```
if (strcmp(entrada->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(entrada->d_name,"..")==0);
else {
  if (entrada->d_type == DT_DIR){
    strcpy(nombre,root);
    strcat(nombre,"/");
    strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);
    findfiles(nombre,p,tam);
  }
  else {
    strcpy(nombre,root);
    strcat(nombre,"/");
    strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);
    p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
    p[*tam]=nombre;
    *tam = *tam +1;
  }
}
```

Es equivalente a esto:

```
if ( strcmp(entrada->d_name,".") && strcmp(entrada->d_name,"..") )
{
  strcpy(nombre,root);
  strcat(nombre,"/");
  strcat(nombre,entrada->d_name);

  if (entrada->d_type == DT_DIR)
    findfiles(nombre,p,tam);
  else
  {
    p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
    p[*tam]=nombre;
    *tam++;
  }
}
```

Además, hay que tener cuidado a la hora de copiar strings. En las siguientes líneas:

```
    p[*tam]=malloc(strlen(nombre)+1);
    p[*tam]=nombre;
```

Estás haciendo una reserva de memoria y después modificas dicho puntero por otro, con lo que pierdes la reserva inicial y tu programa acaba con fugas de memoria. Otro efecto colateral de esta situación es que varios elementos de `p` acabarán apuntando al mismo sitio, luego tener entradas repetidas será inevitable. Además, liberar la memoria asociada será problemático porque no se puede liberar dos veces la misma reserva de memoria:

```
char* ptr = malloc(100);
free(ptr); // OK
free(ptr); // ERROR
```

Ahí debes hacer uso de `strcpy`, como has hecho anteriormente:

```
strcpy(p[*tam],nombre);
```

Otro problema que tiene tu código es el siguiente:

```
void findfiles(char *root,char *p[],int *tam)
```

En la función anterior, ¿Qué tamaño tiene asignado el arreglo `p`?

Lo pregunto porque en no haces ninguna comprobación para garantizar que no se sobrepasan sus límites.

Lo que deberías hacer, en mi opinión, es que `p` se vaya redimensionando según las necesidades, es decir, según la cantidad de ficheros que se encuentren. Esto lo puedes conseguir de dos formas diferentes:

**1. Redimensionando el arreglo cada vez que haga falta**

En este caso antes de añadir un fichero a la lista se comprueba si el arreglo está lleno, en cuyo caso se redimensiona para dotarlo de más capacidad.

Esta solución es la más sencilla de implementar, pero también la más costosa puesto que llamar a `realloc` implica copiar el contenido del arreglo viejo en el nuevo.

Nota que para aplicar esta solción necesitas una nueva variable que indique la capacidad total del arreglo.

```
if ( tam == max_size )
{
  char** p_temp = (char**)realloc(p,(max_size+100)*sizeof(char*));
  if( p_temp )
    p = p_temp;
  else
    // ERROR AL REASIGNAR LA MEMORIA
}
// Se añaden nuevos ficheros a la lista
```

**2. Usar una lista enlazada simple para ir almacenando los resultados y después volcar todo al arreglo**

Esta solución tiene como ventaja que `p` únicamente ocupará el tamaño que necesite, ni más ni menos. Su principal desventaja está en implementar una lista enlazada simple para ir almacenando los resultados.

En este caso no te pongo código porque la lista enlazada podrías programarla de cero o usar una librería de terceros y la solución a aplicar en cada caso podría variar.

Un saludo.